# Always regenerate Sphinx documents containing a specific directive

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docutils

Sphinx usually incrementally builds the documentation which means that only files that have been changed will be regenerated. I am wondering if there is a way to tell Sphinx to always regenerate certain files which may not directly have been changed but are influenced by changes in other files. More specific: Is there a way to tell Sphinx to always regenerate files that contain a certain directive? The documentation I am working on relies on the possibility to collect and reformat information from other pages with the help of directives quite frequently. A clean (`make clean && make [html]`) and/or full (`sphinx-build -a`) build takes significantly longer than an incremental build. Additionally, manually keeping track of files which contain the directive might be complicated. The documentation is written by 10+ authors with limited experience in writing Sphinx documentation.

But even in less complex scenarios you might face this 'issue':
For instance [sphinx.ext.todo](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/todo.html) contains a directive called `todolist` which collects todos from the whole documentation. If I create a file containing all the todos from my documentation (basically an empty document just containing the `todolist` directive) the list is not updated until I make a clean build or alter the file.

If you want to test it yourself: Create a documentation with `sphinx-quickstart` and stick to the default values except for

```
'> todo: write "todo" entries that can be shown or hidden on build (y/n) [n]: y'
```

Add a file in `source` called `todos.rst` and reference this file from `index.rst`.

Content of the `index.rst`:

```
Welcome to sphinx-todo's documentation!
=======================================

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2

   todos


.. todo::
 I have to do this


Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

Content of `todos.rst`:

```
.. _`todos`:

List of ToDos
=============

.. todolist::
```

Assuming you use the `html` output you will notice that `todos.html` will not change when you add todos to `index.html`.

tl;dr: How -- if possible -- do I include files containing a specific directive (e.g. `todolist`) into an *incremental* build of Sphinx without the need of manually keeping track of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default Sphinx will only update output for new or changed files. This is buried under [`sphinx-build -a`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-build.html#cmdoption-sphinx-build-a).

At the end of the documentation of command options for `sphinx-build`:

> You can also give one or more filenames on the command line after the source and build directories. Sphinx will then try to build only these output files (and their dependencies).

You could either invoke `sphinx-build` directly or through your makefile, depending on the makefile that shipped with your version of Sphinx (you can customize the makefile, too).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Your answer supports my current impression that you either have to build everything or directly specify the files you want to rebuilt. I was hoping for a neat little hidden 'whitelist' keyword for directives/files or some best practise preprocessing (e.g. before-build-hook) but this does not seem to exist.

Comment: Apparently, you can use `BuildEnvironment.note_reread()` in your directive accessing an instance of the build env via `self.env` in your directive's `run()`: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/8040#issuecomment-668047534.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record: I benchmarked several solutions.

I created a function called `touch_files` in my `conf.py`. It searches for strings in files and -- if found -- touches the file to trigger a rebuilt:

```
def touch_files(*args):
    # recursively search the 'source' directory
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.'):
        # check all rst files
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.rst'):
            cur = os.path.join(root, filename)
            f = open(cur)
            # access content directly from disk
            s = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
            if any(s.find(d) != -1 for d in args):
                # if a string pattern has been found alter the edit 
                # time of the file
                os.utime(cur, None)
            f.close()

# actually call the function
touch_files('.. todolist::')
```

`touch_files` can be called with a variable amount of arguments and will edit a file when ONE of the arguments has been found. I tried to optimize the function with regular expression but this did not achieve much. Reading the file content directly from the disk with `mmap` seemed to have a minor impact.

This is the result of 78 files total from which 36 contain one of two directives.

```
Command                                 Time     Comment
time make html                          2.3 s    No changes
time sh -c 'make clean && make html'   13.3 s
time make htmlfull                      9.4 s    sphinx-build -a    
time make html                          8.4 s    with 'touch_files'
'touch_files'                           0.2 s    tested with testit
```

**Result**: Every command has been called just a few times (except 'touch_files') and therefore lack statistical reliability. Sphinx requires roughly 2.3 seconds to check the documentation for changes without doing anything. A clean build requires 13.3 seconds which is much longer than a build with `sphinx-build -a`. If we just rebuilt 36 out of 78 files, the built process is slightly faster, although I doubt a significant difference could be found here. The overhead of 'touch_files' is rather low. Finding the strings is quite cheap compared to editing the timestamps.

**Conclusion**: As [Steve Piercy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44758406/1617563) pointed out, using `sphinx-build -a` seems to be the most reasonable approach. At least for my use case. Should a file which does not contain a directive in question result in long building times `touch_files` might be useful though.